# What is a factorized Gaussian distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, bayesian-network

I am reading the post [Online Bayesian Deep Learning in Production at Tencent](https://www.inference.vc/online-bayesian-deep-learning-in-production-at-tencent/) about Bayesian deep learning. It mentions that we can approximate a distribution $p_t(w\mid x)$ by a simple distribution $q_t(t)$. Then it mentions that this distribution can be a factorized Gaussian distribution.

What is a factorized Gaussian distribution?

Answer (score 12):

In this context factorised means that each of the marginal distributions are independent. Here a factorised Gaussian distribution just means that the covariance matrix is diagonal.

Comment: Could you please explain what an independent marginal distribution is?

Comment: If we have a set of variables that are jointly drawn from a multivariate normal distribution then each of their marginal distributions is a univariate normal distribution. In the case of two variables they're independent if $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$. You can see from that definition how we're factorising the joint distribution into the product of marginals.